# Convert <log4j:configuration> (in log4j 1.x) to <Configuration> (in log4j 2.x)

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I need to migrate log4j 1.x XML configuration to log4j 2.x configuration XML. I couldn't find log4j2 equivalent configurations to some of the log4j1 configuration attributes. I have following line in log4j1 XML:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" threshold="trace" reset="true" debug="false">
```

I want to have an equivalent log4j2 configuration, something like:

```
<Configuration>
```

I know `status="debug"` would enable extensive logging of log4j2 internals. But by default it is turned off as I need. Could anyone suggest the equivalent configurations for `threshold="trace"` and `reset="true"` in log4j2 XML?

Answer (score 1):

Log4j2 does not support either of those attributes.

Comment: Is there a loss of functionality if I plainly ignore those attributes? Are there no alternate configurations? I know that I can set threshold at different level of hierarchy but I couldn't find anything around `reset="true"`

Comment: reset="true" doesn't make sense with Log4j 2. Log4j 1 combines the logging configuration into the Logger objects that an application requests. Log4j 2 uses separate LoggerConfig objects for the configuration. When a reconfigure happened in Log4j 1 with reset="true" all the Logger objects would be cleared - which meant there was no logging configuration at all during that time. Log4j 2 will construct a brand new Configuration and then repoint all the Loggers to it when the reconfiguration is complete. 

To accomplish what the threshold setting does set a global filter in Log4j2.